# How to Toggle div Content with multiple divs?

Tags: toggle, jquery

I want to **toggle** my content using two different divs. If I click on div with class "open" this open contents and to close the contents i click on separate div with class "close".

```
<div class="open"></div>
<div class="close"></div>

<div id="contents"></div>
```

How can I accomplish this?

This is my script:

```
$('.open').toggle(function(){
    $('#contents').hide();
    $('.wrapper').animate({'width':'200px'}).end().find('.content').animate({ 'right': '30px' }) 
}, 
function() {
    $('#contents').show();      
    $('.wrapper').animate({'width':'40px'}).end().find('.content').animate({ 'right': '0' })    
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: toggle event handler has been deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: I tried with `}, function(.close) {` but doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the click event handler to the separate elements

```
$('div.open').click(function(){
   // your open code here
});
$('div.close').click(function(){
   // your close code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

separate them in 2 click functions

```
$('.close').click(function(){
    $('#contents').hide();
    $('.wrapper').animate({'width':'200px'}).end().find('.content').animate({ 'right': '30px' }) 
});
$('.open').click(function() {
    $('#contents').show();      
    $('.wrapper').animate({'width':'40px'}).end().find('.content').animate({ 'right': '0' })    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".open").click(function() {
    $("#contents").show();
});

$(".close").click(function() {
    $("#contents").hide();
});
```